# how can I know size of each generation in java heap with jmx

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, jmx, heap-dump

*jmap* can know size of each generation, but I want to monitor my java process real time.

With *jmx*, `MemoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed()` can get the total heap size. But I cannot find any method to get:

1. Size of New (Young) and Tenured (Old) generations;
2. Size of Eden and each Survivor in New generations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans()`. It shows all the memory regions. Depending on the GC you used, the names differ. `pool.getCollectionUsage().getInit()` gives the initial size of a pool. `pool.getName()` is for example 'G1 Eden Space' or 'G1 Old Gen'  or 'G1 Survivor Space' if you use G1 GC.

`pool.getUsage().getUsed()` returns as well the amount of used memory for that region.

Comment: `pool.getCollectionUsage().getUsed()` always got `0`. And `pool.getUsage().getUsed()` works.

Comment: Guess I messed up between the two :). Will edit it the answer :).