# Java: reliably allocate large array on heap

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, heap-memory

**The Task**

Allocate X=4..8MB of byte array (on heap), e.g. using ByteBuffer.allocate() such that it will not cause an OutOfMemoryError. It is not allowed to split the array and process it in smaller portions. Note that the allocation happens on heap, this is not a direct ByteBuffer.

**The Challenges**

- Memory can be fragmented, and if there is enough memory (greater than X), a continuous portion of size X bytes may still be unavailable to allocate the array (any API to find out is there a continuous region of X bytes is available probably would help).
- Heap memory is divided into regions to keep objects of different generations, and an object cannot span two or more regions of the heap: [Huge arrays throws out of memory despite enough memory available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298455/huge-arrays-throws-out-of-memory-despite-enough-memory-available)  and [Large Array allocation across young and tenured portions of java Heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198271/large-array-allocation-across-young-and-tenured-portions-of-java-heap)
- Large objects are immediately allocated in a tenured region, but it is tricky to reliably reason about which region exactly even using `ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans()`: [how can I know size of each generation in java heap with jmx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55496877/how-can-i-know-size-of-each-generation-in-java-heap-with-jmx) Some JVMs dynamically adjust LOAs: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdk-java-technology/8?topic=SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.vm.80.doc/docs/mm_allocation_loa.html

**Question**

Is there a way in Java to code as follows?

```
if (<I can reliably allocate an array sized X bytes on heap right now>) {
     ByteBuffer.allocate(X);
}
```

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s a fundamental problem with the idea to do

> ```java
> if (<I can reliably allocate an array sized X bytes on heap right now>) {
>     ByteBuffer.allocate(X);
> }
> ```

known as “check-then-act” anti-pattern. Regardless of how the check in the `if`’s condition is supposed to work, you need to ensure that it doesn’t change between the check and the subsequent action, i.e. the allocation.

To ensure that the result doesn’t change, you’d not only need to stop all other threads of the same JVM from performing allocations (or concurrent garbage collection from completing) but also prevent all other processes of the same machine from allocating memory, as it is possible that the operating system did not reserve memory for your JVM exclusively but still allows other processing to take it right at this point.

The condition itself has the challenges already named in your question and, as you said yourself, all this fiddling with implementation specific memory regions might be moot when the JVM is capable of reconfiguring them on-the-fly. Since this is usually done as response to the result of a garbage collection, you’d need to perform a full garbage collection first, to determine the resulting situation. Only in this case we were able to be sure that another GC won’t change the situation, if we were able to stop all other threads and processes from doing allocations.

And on some JVMs the only way to reliably trigger a garbage collection, is to perform an actual allocation.

So you need a way to atomically perform the check, followed by an actual allocation that ensures that the memory stays available to you no matter what happens in the environment or an answer that the memory is not available. This mechanism does exist. Just call `ByteBuffer.allocate(X)` and if it completes normally, the returned reference ensures that the memory stays available as long as you keep it. Otherwise, the thrown `OutOfMemoryError` signals the unavailability of the memory. Since this mechanism exist, there is no reason to provide a second one with the same outcome.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no reliable way to do this in Java.

There are several ways to get estimates or best-effort guesses for the available memory, but nothing reliable. Also note that even if there were such a thing, another thread could change the available amount between the condition and the call to allocate.

This [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807797/java-get-available-memory/18366283#18366283) contains a way to get such an estimate, and also explains some of the reasons why this can not be reliable.